# Which compiler should I use for installing CUDA 8?

Tags: cuda, compiler

Which compiler should I use for installing CUDA 8? Is there an official page that associates the CUDA versions to the compiler to use?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?  CUDA 8 takes gcc-5, which isn't even offered anymore in the standard repos for later releases.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 8 takes gcc-5, which is still offered in the standard repositories (with gcc-7 being the default compiler for Ubuntu 10.04).  Consider using a later CUDA install if your hardware allows it.  Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5
```

And if the ar-5, nm-5, and ranlib-5 do not get automatically brought in as dependencies, install them too.
Then add links to these old versions in your cuda/bin directory (which should have been added as the first location in your PATH environment variable:

cd wherever you installed cuda then add the link(s):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 gcc
```

### and for ar, nm, ranlib, and g++.

A few things could be wrong here.
First, the sample Makefiles may have embedded in them an explicit path used to find the nvcc compiler (/usr/local/cuda), which may be overridden if you
export CUDA_PATH=whereeverItReallyIs

Second, The actual error message may say gcc when it really should be complaining about g++.  You need to install and add the g++-5 link too, like you did for gcc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me with this :) I've tried your solution and I got the following error after running:  `sudo sh cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-8.0`; the error: ```Error: unsupported compiler: 5.5.0. Use --override to override this check.```. Any idea why and how to solve this?